# How do I apply change of variables to improper integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

In Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis chapter 6, Rudin discusses change of variables with Riemann-Stieltjes Integration.[image: 6.19 Theorem(change of variable)]

Can this theorem be manipulated and applied to 'improper' integral that Rudin mentions in Exercise 7 and 8?

What if a function Φ such that for any B>0, Φ maps [0,B] onto [0,c] such that C(B):=inf{Φ(x):0≤x≤B} is monotonically decreasing and C(B) converges to 0 as B goes to infinity, Φ is differentiable on any [0,B], and Φ' is Riemann-Integrable?

Does such function exist? If so, is it easily applicable?

Comment: No continuous $\Phi$ could map a compact interval onto a non-compact interval. For the purposes of integration though, if say $\{0\}$ has measure $0$, then you can replace $[0,1]$ with $(0,1]$.

Comment: How about a function Φ such that for any B>0, Φ maps [0,B] onto [0,c] such that C(B):=inf{Φ(x):0≤x≤B} is monotonically decreasing and C(B) converges to 0, Φ is differentiable on any [0,B] and Φ' is Riemann-Integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  For example,

$$\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{x}-1$$

maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: But the derivative of the function is not Riemann-Integrable. Sorry, that's my fault. I edited the question so please look again.